# Can use number as field name

Tags: mysql

I am using php and mysql. For some purpose I have used number as a field name.
My query is,

```
"SELECT `id`, `keyword`, `205` from `rtr3a_keyword_hitcount` WHERE keyword = 'whirlpool'"
```

The output array looks like,
  [id] => 1
  [keyword] => xxx

But 205 column and value does not displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [It works fine in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edcfe/1/0). We need to see some PHP code.

Comment: Actually I did another method to solve my issue, but it was long ago. So i forgot the process. Please omit this question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is because in your php 205 is interpreted like a numeric and not like a field

Is like if you would do Select id , 200 from table
200 si returned like a number.
You should use ` delimiter or try to do a Select *.

I strongly recommend like the best option is to do a alter table because this will give you problems in the future.